# Python how to join/merge Pandas dataframes with matching columns of specific values from different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, conditional-statements

I have two different datasets a and b. I want to left join b to a but I want to join to a where only **left join b['ColA'] and b['ColC'] to matching a['ColA'] and a['ColC']==1**

something like `expected_table = pd.merge(a,b, left_on=['ColA', ['ColC']==1 ] ,rigth_on = ['ColA',['ColC']==0])`

```
a =  pd.DataFrame({"ColA":["num 1", "num 2", "num 3"],
                   "ColB":[5,6,7],
                   "ColC":[1,1,0]})

b =  pd.DataFrame({"ColA":["num 1", "num 2", "num 4"],
                   "Colx":[10,16,71],
                   "Coly":[0,0,0]})
```

`Coly` is all equal 0

````
expected= pd.DataFrame({"ColA":["num 1", "num 2", "num 3"],
                   "ColB":[5,6,7],
                   "ColC":[1,1,0], 
                   "Colx":[10,16,None]})```
````

I solve it by creating a new column on b table that matches same value with `a['colx']`.

But I wonder if there is a way to let you use conditions in merge/join process like in sql.

Comment: Any question with the answer below ?

Comment: oaky, we are actually not merging based on condition but adding query behind to slice it as we wish.  It is a good asnwer thank you, since pandas dont have a supporting feature, this will work well to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

There is no feature in Pandas to directly use conditions in merge/join process like in sql.  Anyway, we can simulate this by chaining the Pandas [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function and perform the filtering by [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) which has syntax like sql where condition syntax.

To do this, you can do a left join on `a` and `b` on matching `ColA` and set `indicator=True` for us to distinguish whether the merged row entry is from `a` only or from merging both `a` and `b`.

Then, use [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to filter on the required condition that if merging from both, `ColC == 1` and `Coly == 0`.  Otherwise, if only from `a`, we keep the row.

```
df_out = (pd.merge(a, b, left_on='ColA', right_on ='ColA', how='left', indicator=True)
            .query('(_merge == "left_only") | ((ColC == 1) & (Coly == 0))')
         )
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)


    ColA  ColB  ColC  Colx  Coly     _merge
0  num 1     5     1  10.0   0.0       both
1  num 2     6     1  16.0   0.0       both
2  num 3     7     0   NaN   NaN  left_only
```

Then, we can drop the unwanted columns by [`.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), as follows:

```
df_out = df_out.drop(['Coly', '_merge'], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)

    ColA  ColB  ColC  Colx
0  num 1     5     1  10.0
1  num 2     6     1  16.0
2  num 3     7     0   NaN
```